# Function $ f(x)=a_1 \cos(b_1 x) + \dots + a_n \cos(b_n x)$ has root value

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ and $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$ to be positive real numbers.

Prove that for function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$
f(x)=a_1 \cos(b_1 x) + \dots + a_n \cos(b_n x)
$$
there exists at least one $x_0$ such as $f(x_0)=0$.

Comment: what does it mean for a function to have "root value"? Please clarify.

Comment: there exists at least one $x_0$ such as $f(x_0)=0$

Comment: Ok. Can you show the function must take at least one positive value and one negative value? If so then by continuity it must take the value zero.

Comment: Does positive mean that $a_i,b_i>0 \forall i$?

Comment: @MachineLearner yes